# Use MethodChannel from an Isolate without plugin

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-method-channel

Is it possible to call a native function using MethodChannel from an Isolate? [The documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab#executing-channel-handlers-on-background-threads) only shows how to adapt the native code in the case of plugins. However, I'm using MethodChannel as described in the page linked above, without creating a plugin.

Code in Flutter Isolate:

```
DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
const methodChannel = MethodChannel('MethodChannel');
final double result = await methodChannel.invokeMethod('getAltitude');
```

Code in MainActivity.kt:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine); // saw this in another thread.  Tested with and without it    
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)    
    val taskQueue = flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger.makeBackgroundTaskQueue()

     MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "MethodChannel", StandardMethodCodec.INSTANCE,taskQueue).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      if (call.method == "getAltitude") {
        val altitude = "xxx"
        result.success(altitude)
       
      } else {
        result.notImplemented()
      }
    }    
    
  }
```

This is the error I get:

```
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAltitude on channel MethodChannel))
```

Comment: Since it is so easy to create a plugin project - and then to depend your main project on that plugin project, why wouldn't you do that if it makes the plugin code easier?

Comment: I just did this, I created a plugin for the getAltitude function. Surprisingly, I can use the plugin from an isolate without adapting the code as specified in the docs section I linked (so without using task queue).

Comment: i want to know this as well

Comment: Same issue here. Weird that you need to create a whole plugin to run methods from another isolate